# Flutter ios initState execution

Tags: ios, flutter, connection, flutter-dependencies

I want to check Internet connection and show a bottomSheet in the initState() when the app load.
It works pretty well on android but seems to not listening first time the app load.
Here is the code:

```
@override
initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectivity = Connectivity();
    subscription =
    connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
     if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        controller = _scaffoldKey.currentState
            .showBottomSheet<Null>((BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                 Divider(),
                 Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                   child: Text(
                     'Check your internet connection!',
                   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                 )),
        ],
      ));
    });

  } else if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
      result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
    controller.close();
  }
});
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you need ? The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @ciplionat this code works on android but not on ios.
What I mean is, imagine that you open the app without internet connection. I want to show the bottomSheet. Actually It works on both android and ios when you enter the app with connection. But not when you open the app without connection on ios.